How do these 2 stacking contexts interact with each other?
I have this code


.red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(50px);
}

.blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: -50px;
  transform: translateX(1px);
}
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>



Both <div>'s establish a new stacking context, and when you have 2 competing 2 child contexts for sibling elements, the element that comes later in the HTML wins (comes on top). Correct me if I'm wrong.
Now I was trying to make the "red"  appear on top. I've tried 2 approaches:

Adding z-index to each element. I've added a higher z-index to "red". This did not work.

However, when I added position: relative in addition to z-index for both elements, suddenly the red element appeared on top.


Here is the final (working version) on CodePen.
My question was: I'm not quite sure why this works. I have 2 properties ("transform" and "position" which establish 2 stacking contexts).
How do they interact with each other in a way that, when I add them in addition to z-index, I get what I want vs. using z-index separately?

the concept of "stacking context" is irrelevant here. You have to consider the "painting order" and note that z-index has no effect without position set
